# Regex to pick specific words

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to pick specific words from string. Words are dynamic.

```
const KEY_VAL_MAP = { car: vehicle };
const KEY  = 'car';

let sampleString = 'hey this i need to replace car ${car}';

sampleString = sampleString.replace(new RegExp(`\\b(?:${KEY})\\b`, 'g'), KEY_VAL_MAP[_key]);
```

**the result expected is :  'hey this i need to replace vehicle ${car}';**

With the above regex it will replace every `car` with `vehicle`. What needs to be updated in regex so that everything in string under `${}` is excluded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead and behind to exclude the matches for words in between `${}`.

```
(?<!\$\{)\bcar\b(?!\})
```

```js
const KEY_VAL_MAP = { car: 'vehicle' };
const KEY  = 'car';

let sampleString = 'hey this i need to replace car ${car}';

sampleString = sampleString.replace(new RegExp(`(?<!\\$\\{)\\b${KEY}\\b(?!\\})`, 'g'), KEY_VAL_MAP[KEY]);

console.log(sampleString);
```

---

Also, some browsers(such as safari) doesn't support lookbehinds. So if you want you code also work on those browsers, you may use another workaround using a capture group:

```
(\$\{car\})|\bcar\b
```

If the group catches anything, don't touch. Otherwise replace.

```js
const KEY_VAL_MAP = { car: 'vehicle' };
const KEY  = 'car';

let sampleString = 'hey this i need to replace car ${car}';

sampleString = sampleString.replace(new RegExp(`(\\$\\{${KEY}\\})|\\b${KEY}\\b`, 'g'), (_, g) => g ?? KEY_VAL_MAP[KEY]);

console.log(sampleString);
```

Comment: the above regex will replace words inside `${}`. What's required here is to not replace words in `${}`

Comment: That's what you meant... let me fix it

Answer (score 4):

You may use this regex to avoid matching `${...}` substring:

```
(?<!\$\{)\bcar\b(?!})
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eSNA87/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<!\$\{)`: Negative Lookbehind to assert that we don't have `${` before our matching word
- `\bcar\b`: Match full word `car`
- `(?!})`: Negative Lookahead to assert that we don't have `}` after our matching word

**Code:**

```js
const KEY_VAL_MAP = { car: 'vehicle' };
const KEY  = 'car';

let sampleString = 'hey this i need to replace car ${car}';

sampleString = sampleString.replace(new RegExp(`(?<!\\$\\{)\\b(?:${KEY})\\b(?!})`, 'g'), KEY_VAL_MAP[KEY]);

console.log(sampleString);
```